# Cassandra only one row is inserted when expected 100k

Tags: python-3.x, cassandra, cql

I tried to `CQL Python driver` to insert 100k rows,

```
# no_of_rows = 100k
for row in range(no_of_rows):
    session.execute("INSERT INTO test_table (key1, key2, key3) VALUES ('test', 'test', 'test'"))
```

but only one row is inserted into `test_table` (using `Cassandra CQL Shell` and `select * from test_table`), how to fix the issue?

UPDATE

If I tried

```
for row in range(no_of_rows):
    session.execute("INSERT INTO test_table (key1, key2, key3) VALUES ('test' + str(row), 'test', 'test'"))
```

no rows were inserted, here `key1` is the primary key.

`describe test_table`,

```
CREATE TABLE test_keyspace.test_table (
key1 text PRIMARY KEY,
key2 text,
key3 text
) WITH bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
AND comment = ''
AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
AND default_time_to_live = 0
AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
AND max_index_interval = 2048
AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
AND min_index_interval = 128
AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE';
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cassandra primary keys are unique.  100000 in-place writes to the same key(s) leaves you with 1 row.

Which means if your primary key structure is `PRIMARY KEY(key1,key2,key3)` and you INSERT `'test','test','test'` 100000 times...

...it'll write `'test','test','test'` to the same partition 100000 times.

To get your Python code to work, I made some adjustments, such as creating a separate variable for the `key` (key1) and using a prepared statement:

```
pStatement = session.prepare("""
    INSERT INTO test_table (key1, key2, key3) VALUES (?, ?, ?);
""")

no_of_rows=100000

for row in range(no_of_rows):
    key='test' + str(row)
    session.execute(pStatement,[key,'test','test'])
```

> using Cassandra CQL Shell and `select * from test_table`

I feel compelled to mention, that both **multi-key** (querying for more than one partition key at a time) and **unbound queries** (SELECTs without a WHERE clause) are definite **anti-patterns** in Cassandra.  They may appear work fine in a dev/test environment.  But when you get to a production-scale cluster with dozens of nodes, these types of queries will introduce a lot of network time into the equation, as they will have to scan each node to compile the query results.

Comment: I have tried `test + str(row)` as values for primary key `key1`, but no rows were inserted. what's the problem here? see my updated OP

Comment: @daiyue can you also edit your post to include your table definition?  That'll help.

Comment: I have modified the OP to show the table definition.

Comment: @daiyue Edit made.  I was able to get your code to work with a few adjustments.

Answer (score 1):

Your new code has a bug in string concatenation. It should be:

```
for row in range(no_of_rows):
    session.execute("INSERT INTO test_table (key1, key2, key3) VALUES ('test" + str(row) + "', 'test', 'test')")
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but it didn't work. no rows were inserted